# How to see all Pull requests that im tagged as a reviewer

Tags: github

In github you can add a number of reviewers. 
What I'm looking for is, as a user, to list all the pull requests that I'm currently tagged as a reviewer in.

I have looked at the views that's available in the "pull request" link but this don't meet my demands.

For instance if I go to the "Review requested" i get a "No results matched your search"

Is there someone who has a either a nice search query for achieving this?

Answer (score 32):

Try the link https://github.com/pulls/review-requested, which shows you all Pull Requests that you've been tagged in as a reviewer.

Note that you may have to click the `Open` or `Closed` buttons on that page to filter the Pull Requests you wish to see.

The equivalent Github search is: `is:open is:pr review-requested:<username> archived:false`

Comment: This is the behaviour that I expected but alas it's not working for me.

Then there are probably some issue with github.

Have contacted them and they are looking into the issue.

Hopefully they will find the issue and sort it out.

Comment: Great, please update us when you have more information!

Comment: This link will show the PR if you haven't reviewed it yet. Once you've sent the review, it won't show it even if the PR is still open and you're still in the list of reviewers.
@Nosfert did they ever come back to you?

Comment: Doesn't provide a solution to the question asked.

Comment: @Neets This is really annoying behaviour. The fact that you've reviewed it shouldn't change the fact that you've been requested to review it and makes looking up PRs you've approved unnecessarily tedious.

Comment: It's not just sending the review - even adding a single comment to the PR means it no longer shows up in the list :-(

Answer (score 29):

Unfortunately is is not possible to list all the pull request where you are tagged as a reviewer in one single search.

Primary reason for this is that Github search doesn't support an "OR" operator.

To get list off all pull request you are tagged as a reviewer you need to look at:

1. All pull request you have been assigned to review.

   Search string: `is:open is:pr review-requested:cniesen-kingland`

   > review-requested:USERNAME matches pull requests where a specific person is requested for review. Requested reviewers are no longer listed in the search results after they review a pull request. If the requested person is on a team that is requested for review, then review requests for that team will also appear in the search results.
2. All pull request that you reviewed.

   Search string: `is:pr reviewed-by:cniesen-kingland`

   > reviewed-by:USERNAME matches pull requests reviewed by a particular person.

Reference: [Github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-pull-request-review-status-and-reviewer)

Comment: This is the correct answer - especially for seeing all PRs that you have already reviewed.

Answer (score 5):

You can now use the `involves` filter. With this you can have a single place to show all the pull requests you are involved in. Even if you commented or approved the PR it should still appear in the list.

```
is:open is:pr involves:@me archived:false
```

https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+involves%3A%40me+archived%3Afalse+

Description of the involves filter:

> You can use the involves qualifier to find issues that in some way involve a certain user. The involves qualifier **is a logical OR between the author, assignee, mentions, and commenter qualifiers for a single user.** In other words, this qualifier finds issues and pull requests that were either created by a certain user, assigned to that user, mention that user, or were commented on by that user.

([source](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-a-user-thats-involved-in-an-issue-or-pull-request))

[image]

Comment: Best answer so far, if you are looking for a single query instead of two separate ones. Not perfect, not terrible, but it works, thanks

Comment: This solved my problem of being able to find PRs that need my attention in a single place. Github then adds a blue highlight to the left of the rows where new unread activity has happened.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this via GitHub search by searching for something like:

`assignee:bsinky is:pr is:open`

That will show you all items you are assigned to that are open PRs.

If you are looking to query the GitHub API for this:

`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=assignee:{username}+is:pr+is:open`

Comment: Well assignee and reviewer is not the same.
We usually never add an assignee and only reviewers.